# Array of objects - calculate mean values of properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have this array of objects

```
audioFeatures = [
    {danceability: 10, loudness: 2, instrumentalness: 4, energy: 5, acousticness: 7},
    {danceability: 6, loudness: 3, instrumentalness: 8, energy: 9, acousticness: 5},
    {danceability: 7, loudness: 5, instrumentalness: 6, energy: 2, acousticness: 5},
    {danceability: 8, loudness: 10, instrumentalness: 9, energy: 7, acousticness: 2},
]
```

And I want to calculate a mean value for each property i.e. danceability should = (10+6+7+8)/4 and so on. I have got this working through a plethora of for loops but it seems really inefficient and I ideally want to end up with one object containing each mean value which I haven't figured out.

Does anyone know of a nice way of doing this. I'm coding this in JavaScript but any advise would be appreciated and I can try implement it. I have been trying map but can't quite get my head around how to apply it to this (maybe nested map lol, that's probably not a good idea)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need two for loops:

```js
audioFeatures = [
    {danceability: 10, loudness: 2, instrumentalness: 4, energy: 5, acousticness: 7},
    {danceability: 6, loudness: 3, instrumentalness: 8, energy: 9, acousticness: 5},
    {danceability: 7, loudness: 5, instrumentalness: 6, energy: 2, acousticness: 5},
    {danceability: 8, loudness: 10, instrumentalness: 9, energy: 7, acousticness: 2},
]

const average = {};

for (const feature of audioFeatures) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(feature)) {
    if (!average[key]) average[key] = 0;
    average[key] += value / audioFeatures.length;
  }
}

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the n<sup>th</sup> part of the value for the averages by iterating the array and the key/value pairs of the objects.

```js
var audioFeatures = [{ danceability: 10, loudness: 2, instrumentalness: 4, energy: 5, acousticness: 7 }, { danceability: 6, loudness: 3, instrumentalness: 8, energy: 9, acousticness: 5 }, { danceability: 7, loudness: 5, instrumentalness: 6, energy: 2, acousticness: 5 }, { danceability: 8, loudness: 10, instrumentalness: 9, energy: 7, acousticness: 2 }],
    averages = audioFeatures.reduce((result, object, _, { length }) => {
        Object
            .entries(object)
            .forEach(([key, value]) => result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + value / length);
        return result;
    }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(averages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Probably because this code is unreadable trying to be "cute".

Comment: @Trasiva, this has nothing to do with "cute", but all with functional programming style.

Comment: Destructuring the length directly from the array parameter of reduce and short-circuiting the key to 0 if it doesn't exist are good tricks! Nice job!

Comment: I'm still curious to see a real-world codebase written in that style :)

Comment: @trincot Go ahead, use code like that in a real work environment. See what your coworkers think of it. That code is *not* easily readable and self-commenting.

Comment: @Trasiva  It wasn't unreadable. Though I understand there could be some frustration if you were being introduced to reduce through this answer, but really I think syntax is reasonable to assume that someone could look up. Pulling apart, playing, and researching code is how you learn the nuances.

Comment: @JonasWilms, look at Haskell, Clojure, ... (e.g. https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_industry)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```js
var audioFeatures = [
 {danceability: 10, loudness: 2, instrumentalness: 4, energy: 5, acousticness: 7},
 {danceability: 6, loudness: 3, instrumentalness: 8, energy: 9, acousticness: 5},
 {danceability: 7, loudness: 5, instrumentalness: 6, energy: 2, acousticness: 5},
 {danceability: 8, loudness: 10, instrumentalness: 9, energy: 7, acousticness: 2},
];
var meanValues = [];
Object.keys(audioFeatures[0]).forEach(key => {
 console.log(key,
  meanValues[key] = (audioFeatures
   .map(a => a[key])
   .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
   / audioFeatures.length));
});
```

1. Find all [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys).
2. For each key create a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (it will return an array of all values of this key)
3. Get sum off array using [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.
4. divide by array length and write it to the variable.